# how to populate data in in select box using ajax in jsp on click of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I am new to `ajax`. In my `.jsp` page, I have 2 components a `select box multiple=true` (list-box) and a `check box`. What I want is when I check on check box then my ajax should fetch data from some other `.jsp` file.

ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#activeFlag").click(function(){
        if(document.getElementById('activeFlag').checked){
            var xmlhttp;    
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","inactive.jsp",true);
            xmlhttp.send();




        }
        else{

        }
    });
});
```

here `s1` is the id for select box. and `activeFlag` is the id for checkbox.

inactive.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
out.print("<option value='1'>Product Name 1 For Category 2</option>" +
                        "<option value='2'>Product Name 2 For Category 2</option>" +
                        "<option value='3'>Product Name 3 For Category 2</option>"
                    );
</body>
</html>
```

But I am not able to get desired output i.e. select field is not getting populated. can some guide me.